# Sections of UV unwrap not taking texture painting

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I Have bought a model I am colouring and animating, however when i come to texture paint it after UV unwrapping, adding material etc there is a part of it that will not be painted, does anyone have any idea what might have gone wrong?

[image: Image1]
[image: Imgage2]
[image: Image3]

Comment: What render engine are you using? Please show some screenshots of the mesh in viewport, UV editor and Properties editor

Comment: maybe normals haven't been recalculated?

Comment: I have checked the normals and they seem to be correct @MCunha

Comment: I am using Blender Render and I have uploaded pictures above @Mr Zak

Comment: So the problem faces are the ones on the hands? Did you try selecting all in Edit mode and checking if those faces are present on the UV map when the image texture is in UV editor? If not remove the texture from editor, select all in viewport and reassign texture in UV editor again (by selecting it from the list of textures). Internal uses face textures to assign image textures to the faces

Comment: Second what Mr. Zak says above, select only the hands and check to see where the UVs are in the editor then, because if they are showing white like that it normally means that the material/object doesn't have a texture on it, and you might have to manually reopen the image while the uvs are active in the uv editor to force the image to the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is a single object made up of multiple meshes, and you are adding materials to these meshes, then you need to make sure the materials are all sharing the image texture that you are painting for them to show the effect the texture is meant to describe.

A color image meant to give color to the model has to be shared for all the materials to be included with the paint - and even if you aren't going to use color on several mesh parts, those materials might be sharing a single image for bumps/gloss/etc.

In the actual case above, OP needs to make sure the model in question isn't composed of multiple objects and is indeed one object - and that the materials added all share the same image texture.

Comment: Thanks but the object is a single object and they are all sharing the same texture image so I still have the problem

Comment: Thanks Guys I have solved the issue. The hands were attached to a different material.

Comment: My answer covers that, maybe mark that as the answer so it is obvious to search users.